# Google Play Console: the meaning of "Active Devices"

Tags: google-play-console

I see it always differ from Installed audience and is mostly more. I am curious how this value gets calculated ?

[image]

I believe it's quite confusing as it has similar meaning as installed audience while it always differ and more surprisingly is always higher number. I was googling but could not find definition for exactly this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Active devices are defined as:

> An active device is one that has been turned on at least once in the previous 30 days.

[Source: View and understand your app's quality and reach](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10770882?hl=en)

##### Installed audience is defined as

> The number of users who have your app installed on at least one device that has been turned on in the last 30 days

(Source: Google Play console)

Comment: I could search better thanks anyway !